# Running Netty Examples in IntelliJ

Tags: netty

Cloning Netty 4.1 from github and opening up the project in IntelliJ causes build errors all over the place as anything under io.netty.util.internal seems to be not accessible from most other places.

Mostly I am really just trying to get the Http2 examples to run, and I think I know how to get them running using the compiled Jars, but seems odd that it does not work in IntelliJ as that is the the recommended way of hacking on Netty as per http://netty.io/wiki/setting-up-development-environment.html

[Example of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDGDr.jpg)

Comment: No idea why, but it seems to open well in my environment. What errors do you find in the module settings dialog? Also, please consider using the vanilla Maven settings and reimporting the project.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps as I've got it working in my setup now for some of the tests:

Two settings I needed to change to get things working in intelliJ were:

`Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Java Compiler` -> (untick) `Use '--release' option for cross-compilation (Java 9 and later)`

The next setting I switched on was under the maven settings so this may/not be relevant:

`Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `Maven` -> (tick) `Use plugin registry`